# Como colocar aspas em uma variável para consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Estou fazendo uma procedure, preciso colocar uma variável varchar na consulta, mas ela não vai com as aspas simples, tentei concatenar assim ou algo parecido mas não adianta:

```
set @comando := concat(@comando, '"'); //ao contrário tbm
set @comando := concat(@comando, classe);
set @comando := concat(@comando, '"');
```

Já tenei colocar aspas tripla também:

```
set @comando := concat(@comando, '''classe''');
```

Qual melhor maneira de concatenar ou de fazer o MySQL reconhecer como um varchar?

Código:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure eixos_caminhao (in classe varchar(3))
begin
    set @comando := 'select count(*) as qtdeCaminhoes';
    set @comando:= concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv where classe = ');
    set @comando := concat(@comando, classe);

    PREPARE myquery FROM @comando;
    EXECUTE myquery;
end $$
delimiter;
```

Comment: Pode fazer assim: `concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv where classe = \'');`

Comment: A barra irá funcionar como um escape e fará com que o próximo caracter faça parte da `string`.

Comment: entao tenho que cercar com \'' pelos dois lados?

Comment: Vou adicionar uma resposta.

Comment: Beleza! agradeço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sempre que estamos montando uma `string` e dentro dessa `string` é necessário ter outra `string`, temos algumas saídas:

1. Como no `SQL` tanto `'` como `"` iniciam e finalizam uma `string`, podemos intercalar esses caracteres para formar uma `string` dentro da outra:

   ```
   set @comando = 'select count(*) as qtdeCaminhoes';
   set @comando = concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv where classe = "');
   set @comando = concat(@comando, classe);
   set @comando = concat(@comando, '"');
   ```

   O resultado disso seria:

   > select count(*) as qtdeCaminhoes from tb_vbv where classe = "conteúdo_de_classe"
2. Mas se caso você realmente queira contornar a `string` com `'`, você pode usar o método anterior invertido(`"'"`), ou utilizar o `\` que é um caracter de escape, o `'` ou `"` após ele, não será considerado como fechamento de uma `string`:

   ```
   set @comando = 'select count(*) as qtdeCaminhoes';
   set @comando = concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv where classe = \'');
   set @comando = concat(@comando, classe);
   set @comando = concat(@comando, '\'');
   ```

Uma outra informação sobre a função `CONCAT` é que ela aceita diversos parâmetros para concatenar de uma única vez, seu código poderia ser resumido para isso por exemplo:

```
set @comando = 'select count(*) as qtdeCaminhoes';
set @comando = concat(@comando, ' from tb_vbv where classe = ');
set @comando = concat(@comando, '\'', classe, '\'');
```

Comment: Entendi! está funcionando agora minha consulta.
Obrigado! me ajudou muito!